# Transactionscope and webHttpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, testing, rest, transactionscope

I have a WCF REST service. I would like to write integration tests for the operations. I was thinking to write those by using HttpWebRequest (as described in [Why does my C# client, POSTing to my WCF REST service, return (400) Bad Request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575893/why-does-my-c-sharp-client-posting-to-my-wcf-rest-service-return-400-bad-req)).

My question is: can I put the HttpWebRequest code in a transactionscope, so that any database operations are rolled back after execution, like:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
   // use HttpWebRequest to execute REST service operation
}
```

Would this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

REST does not support propagation of transactions from the client to the service.

Comment: ok thanks, so there is no (easy) way to write integration test for a REST service?

Comment: Not if you require transactions. One way would be to not require transactions (e.g., use a test database, not the real one, so you can make all the changes you like).