# WCF POST method

Tags: c#, wcf

> {"The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not
>   Allowed}System.InvalidOperationException {System.Net.WebException}

Web Config:

```
      <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="RestService">      
        <endpoint address="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="RestService">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--<protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>-->
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Service :

```
    public test TestPost(test testPost)
    {
        test objtest1 = new test();
        objtest1.Address = "Test";
        objtest1.Name = "Welcome";
        return objtest1;
    }


[DataContract]
public class test
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}


    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       UriTemplate = "TestPost/")]
    test TestPost(test i);
```

Using Fiddler:

```
POST /RESTfulService/Service.svc/web/TestPost/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:50458
Content-Length: 43

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/11.0.0.0
Date: Thu, 19 Dec 2013 07:19:44 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Length: 1647
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: Close
```

GET Method is working fine, when i am trying to use POST method i am getting error

Comment: Show the actual XML request you're POSTing... It seems the problem is in the request, as everything else seems fine.

Comment: I am using Json format. The format is
{
"Name" = "test", 
"Address" = "test"
}

Comment: Ops, I missed that. Ok, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/575893/why-does-my-c-sharp-client-posting-to-my-wcf-rest-service-return-400-bad-req, seems the same.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `{"Name" : "test", "Address" : "test"}`? i.e. `:` in place of `=`.

Comment: By using the above referred link, i used same format of code but cant access that method, please guide me. 
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
       RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
       UriTemplate = "TestPost/")]
    test TestPost(test i);

Comment: used this **{
"Name":"test", 
"Address":"test"
}** but getting error like HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: Just set the content-type to `application/json`. From the fiddler example given, there is no content-type passed. And this is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried above example in my local and found that you are missing one http header called

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Also be sure you pass right json string in request body

```
{"Name" : "test", "Address" : "test"}
```

above trick will help you to get rid of 400 bad request.